# Can I visit tourist attractions while on Umrah/Hajj visa in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: visas, sightseeing, religion, saudi-arabia

If I was granted an Umrah/Hajj visa, Can I visit other parts of Saudi Arabia beside Makkah where Umrah/Hajj is performed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can, a few years ago Saudi Arabia began to allow this and now people on Umrah/Hajj visas can visit any place in Saudi Arabia and it is not limited to Makkah and Madinah only as it was before.

Just make sure to carry your Hajj/Umrah visa with you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can, after performing Umrah you can visit Almadina and stays there until your visa expired. 
May God bless you with visit in the near future!